# MongoDb >4.2 Using aggregation pipeline in updateMany gives $match is not allowed to be used within an update

Tags: mongodb

I read that starting with MongoDB 4.2 you can do aggregation pipeline with `updateMany`. I don't have a good gasp of aggregation pipeline so I thought of doing following to my collection.

```
user{
  id: ObjectId(..),
  books: [
    {
      value: 10,
      type: PDF
    },
    {
      value: 10,
      type: HARDCOVER
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I am trying to lower the value of PDF book from `10` to `5` if user has `PAPER_BACK` or `HARDCOVER` in their `books`

```
db.user.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {$match: {'books' : { $elemMatch: {'value': '10', 'type': 'PDF'}}, 'books.type': {$in: ["PAPER_BACK", "HARDCOVER"]}}},
        {$unwind: '$books'},
        {$match: {"books.type": "PDF"}},
        {$set: {"books.value": "5"}}
    ]
)
```

I thought the above work with the new updateMany() but it's throwing error saying $match is not allowed to be used. Am I misunderstanding completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted $match can't be used within the pipe, nor can $unwind. Use the first arg of updateMany to perform your match.

You are querying the string '10', make sure you change to a number.

```
{
  books: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "value": 10,
      "type": "PDF"
    }
  },
  "books.type": {
    $in: [
      "HARDCOVER",
      "SOFTCOVER"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then to perform the update, use can use $map like this:

```
db.user.updateMany(
  {
    books: {
      $elemMatch: {
        "value": 10,
        "type": "PDF"
      }
    },
    "books.type": {
      $in: [
        "HARDCOVER",
        "SOFTCOVER"
      ]
    }
  },
  [
    {$set: {
      books: {$map: {
        input: "$books",
        in: {$mergeObjects: [
          "$$this",
          {$cond: [
            {$and: [
              {$eq: ["$$this.type", "PDF"]},
              {$eq: ["$$this.value", 10]}
            ]},
            {value: 5},
            null
          ]}
        ]}
      }}
    }}
  ]
)
```

Comment: The query returns the whole document which wasn't what I wanted. Can you explain $map and $mergeObjects and how they go about finding matching `book`s and update them? I've never used them before. Thanks.

Comment: What does returning the whole document have to do with your question?

Comment: You won't get the documents returned from an updateMany call. It returns an object with the counts of documents modified. The query is the same you have in your question, selecting docs that have one book that is a pdf and valued at 10 and also have one hardcover or softcover books. It then iterates over each book subdocument. Since you can't call operators conditionally, $mergeObjects is called on all subdocuments, Then merges in a new value of 5 if the subdocument is both ```type: pdf``` and  ```value: 10``` if not it merges nothing